# GIMP & Photoshop Gaussian Blur issue?

Tags: photoshop, blur, gaussian, gimp

I'm trying hard to nicely blur a red circle but everytime i get gradient levels of red and the image looks choppy.
Before: 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntLY9.png
After:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FibRl.png

How i can acheive a smooth blur ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the visible circles that separate the gradation levels, that is called **banding** Here are some ways to fix that:

1. #### Increase your document's bit level from 8-bit to 16-bit

   This will increase the amount of colors your file can represent, creating more colors that can be used to represent the gradient, making it smoother in appearance.

   - In Photoshop navigate to Image>Mode>16-Bits/Channel
   - In GIMP 2.10 (or higher?), navigate to Image>Precision>16 bit..
2. #### Display or system settings might be unable to display enough colors

   If changing the bit depth does not fix the issue then you might have a hardware or system settings issue.

   - If it's a hardware issue, your monitor might not have the capability to display enough colors to render the gradient smooth
   - If it's system settings you will need to go to your operating systems color depth setting, usually located under the system's display settings.   *It could say something like Millions of Colors, or True Color (32-bit).*
   - The last thing related to settings is that you have a bad color profile set in your system or in your image editing software.  It's beyond the scope of this answer.  *If you don't know how to color calibrate your monitor, then it most likely isn't this and you can skip this.*
3. #### If you *have* to have 8-bits

   If you absolutely have to keep your document in 8-bit color space then you will have to use dithering or add some noise to your image to confuse the viewers brain into seeing a smooth gradient.

   - Noise or dithering will confuse the viewers brain into seeing a smoother gradient by setting some focus on the imperfections of the noise/grain/dithering.  *This doesn't exactly answer your question, but it is about the only option you have if you keep your ultra smooth gradient in 8-bit mode.*

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are applying the Gussain-Blur to the entire image try to Select the red circle and apply the Gussain-Blur filter to it

Comment: Can you give more explanation on how you are  blurring  so that you are getting this result

Comment: do you want a result like this [see the image](http://s24.postimg.org/j46dz3vx1/6yz_Mh_FI.png)

Comment: @LamaSonmez, there is no point with a question like this one. First its not about **programming** a blur effect but just where to click in Photoshop?,  Asker says "How I can achieve a smooth blur" but does not show an example of a so called "smooth blur" when technically a Gaussian or Box blur will actually "smooth blur".